# Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: BSP:R5424: Any ENC_KEY_INFO MUST have exactly one child element

Tags: web-services, soapui, ws-security

This is my WS-Security configuration with SoapUI

1. Server Keystore - contains server's private key + server's public key + Client's public key

   Client Keystore - contains client's private key + client's public key + server's public key

2.WS-Security Configuration – Keystore

```
Source: path to client keystore
Password - client keystore password
```

and

```
Source: path to server keystore
Password - server keystore password
```

[image]

3. Outgoing WS-Security Configuration

*Encryption

```
Keystore - server keystore
Alias - alias of server's public key
Password - Empty (no password required for public key)
Key Identifier Type - X.509
Parts - Name:Body, Namespace:http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/,  Encode:Content
```

[image]

*Signature

```
Keystore - client keystore
Alias - alias of client's private key
Password - password of client's private key
Key Identifier Type - X.509
Parts - Name:Body, Namespace:http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/, Encode:Element
```

[image]

4. Ingoing WS-Security Configuration

   Decrypt Keystore - client keystore

   Signature Keystore - server keystore

   Password - password of client's private key

[image]

5. Applying the ws-security

[image]

6. But the following exception is thrown:

```
19:17:35,494 WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (default task-3) Interceptor for {http://soap.aaa.com/}HelloWorldService has thrown exception, unwinding now: org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: A security error was encountered when verifying the message
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JUtils.createSoapFault(WSS4JUtils.java:216)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:329)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:184)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(PolicyBasedWSS4JInInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:251)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:108)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:134)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:88)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:293)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:212)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:136)
    at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: BSP:R5424: Any ENC_KEY_INFO MUST have exactly one child element
    at org.apache.wss4j.common.bsp.BSPEnforcer.handleBSPRule(BSPEnforcer.java:56)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.ReferenceListProcessor.checkBSPCompliance(ReferenceListProcessor.java:231)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.ReferenceListProcessor.decryptDataRefEmbedded(ReferenceListProcessor.java:151)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.ReferenceListProcessor.handleReferenceList(ReferenceListProcessor.java:103)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.ReferenceListProcessor.handleToken(ReferenceListProcessor.java:67)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.engine.WSSecurityEngine.processSecurityHeader(WSSecurityEngine.java:344)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:280)
    ... 42 more
```

And These are the raw type of soapmessage

```
POST http://localhost:8080/SOAPSecurityWeb/HelloWorld HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 4354
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://soap.aaa.com/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><xenc:ReferenceList xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><xenc:DataReference URI="#ED-762310919C4F29F7D9146737020258012"/></xenc:ReferenceList><ds:Signature Id="SIG-762310919C4F29F7D9146737020256711" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="soap soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:CanonicalizationMethod><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><ds:Reference URI="#id-762310919C4F29F7D9146737020256710"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="soap" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>CQMC6AlBzVr4GlcwEgCTuaLepn4=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>TuzMIyUtSxayHLjfq0TGEEsVXkJdwpL+MGSwwuSQF+9J2t8brCkRvLlNGNvypsORlIPCXPwnxrYG
iFebfSFkIx2hke+Jt9/rRc6stg/iBfeVUrXPn0frOTyi3c7VNZpQIRv7+YE21XXuzxLqMNNoejb4
lDiFnc0VmnNU6GvM/WBf5FXhxr+E2amGcpYbi2yOKMe8pfsj5sRTDUWLkjt4qYU3LmnRpl3kYg8j
ZIF9CgryM5phxrTm18baYwZOWf2whdhNxkd6iEBt/+OMF+uVuW4YStxzKINaR2lSdHquFef3FheA
993frgWKXz8s63nLBLjJXXfLskqhdZdLj7s8Zg==</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-762310919C4F29F7D914673702025678"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-762310919C4F29F7D914673702025679"><wsse:KeyIdentifier EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">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</wsse:KeyIdentifier></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature></wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-762310919C4F29F7D9146737020256710" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><xenc:EncryptedData Id="ED-762310919C4F29F7D9146737020258012" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/><xenc:CipherData><xenc:CipherValue>driG0+hdn4kuBUL545mLKBioB7Cm57Bm0XwyVjkBV8f0VcxPUu4OqkHtRaJYv6MIhmEDDfYiLm5Y2JaijNh7WQnAzWkhh/gfyoXJ4XzVDSOlUPZ1+C4kFgF24zmPHsLhl4oUiLWCDJ3cuAsDNRRzHSHI3T9ONYX9RbekAUwvKFspsAIbYE3YXQuNr7Ux/9GySNxIwBwnd50VvjLaqGNseeBDDAJyKrgSg2REqk9v8IJfh6ue0haLVIMF/xCIO+Qsgvwcpyd5/emSqbXkaFx+d9OCLFgKNs+sTHHy1BybfElsOIamLU9TEdD2PSVP7Frf3ESR2wOBiz0XWBiT1a/1zkjWCh72jbsFzd48x/FXywKbTlF+s5rhCqhBt6lLctlHRIxN8IpQesMNS/jFpc9A3b6dHOvOSx8y5ex4KWIK/Ms=</xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherData></xenc:EncryptedData></soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
Server: WildFly/10
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 299
Date: Fri, 01 Jul 2016 10:50:02 GMT

    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://ws.apache.org/wss4j">ns1:SecurityError</faultcode><faultstring>A security error was encountered when verifying the message</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's much better than the last try with the stacktrace in the comments :-)
Change the `Key Identifier Type` for the encryption to `Binary Security Token` then everything should work.

The reason for the exception is that encryption is done with a symmetric key. You could exchange this key over a secure second channel or (most often) it is encrypted with the clients public key and attached to the request. To get this behaviour in SopaUI you have to change the key identifier type to the mentioned value.

**UPDATE**

To make this work you have to save your changes with "save all" and close and reopen the request window as SoapUI is sometimes a little bit "lazy" about reloading configuration changes. Check the "Raw"-tab of the request to see if your changes have been applied. If not: restart the whole SoapUI and verify that the settings for the Key Identifier Type are still Binary Security Token.

**UPDATE 2**

Be sure that the option "Indicates wether to encrypt the symmetric key into an EncryptedKey or not" is *checked*. Otherwise you will still have an empty KeyInfo-Element.
And change your encryption back to "Content". Encrypting the whole body-element compared to the body-content is seldom preferable.

Comment: Dear Frank, I appreciate your reply. So I changed the **Key Identifier Type** of **Signature** and **Encryption** of outgoing to **Binary Security Token**. But I am afraid the same exception was thrown. Did I miss something?

Comment: I tried everything you taught me. Even more I installed SOAPUI three times. But the same results... I changed Encode:Element of Parts of Encryption. Then different exception is thrown, WARNING [org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain] (default task-19) Interceptor for {http://soap.aaa.com/}HelloWorldService has thrown exception, unwinding now: java.util.NoSuchElementException. Is this another meaning? If you do me a favor, I'd like to attach this simple project. If you give me permission. Any idea?

Comment: The new error is because after encrypting the whole body-element there is no more body-element visible before decryption. So if decryption does not work => NoSuchElement. Strange that the changes did not work. You might attach the project, though I can't promise I'll have enough time to look into it.

Comment: These links will show you the Eclipse Project zip file and SOAPUI Project xml file. Pls, have mercy and take a look at these projects. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3-cLWzEUbhUazBnVDgtdHFwUlE/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3-cLWzEUbhUZkN6b1hlNk80cFk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: And password of client and server is passwd123

Comment: Sorry, the project doesn't build as I have no wildfly installed. Perhaps you could set up your project with maven and springboot so it can be build from scratch without further preconditions?

Comment: Dear Frank! This is url of maven war file - (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3-cLWzEUbhUVjNvSGY5Y3lqbzQ/view?usp=sharing)  (https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3-cLWzEUbhUQWo1QVJXV0d1cG8&usp=sharing)  If there is something wrong, pls don't hesitate asking me. God bless you!

Comment: Doesn't change anything as I still have no wildfly installed. Please try as I suggested in the second update of my answer.

Comment: These are part of exception. 'Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header
 at org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.AlgorithmSuiteValidator.checkSymmetricEncryptionAlgorithm(AlgorithmSuiteValidator.java:149)
 at org.apache.wss4j.dom.processor.EncryptedKeyProcessor.decryptDataRef(EncryptedKeyProcessor.java:550)...'  Any idea? Frank. For your information I attach my ref site. (https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBWS/WS-Security)

Comment: Thank you for your brilliant replies. I do appreciate it.